# Notepad delete anything in brackets

Tags: notepad++

http://prntscr.com/kejcbl

I want to delete anything in brackets, so that I can get the type and the API function.

Comment: Consider posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Am I supposed to click a link to a suspicious URL to get more information about your specific problem? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data, and assuming the bracketed terms would always appear at the end of the line, if they do appear, we can do a find on the following pattern:

```
\s*\[.*?\]\s*$
```

Then, just replace with empty string to remove them.